# values not passing in to database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have included a dynamic dropdown with a textbox in which if i select the `no_of_years(periods)`, it will automatically display the `interest_rate`, and the age of the customer is calculated according to the `date_of_birth`. If the age of the customer is greater than 58 or 58, it's not taking the value inside.

My view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function deposit(){ 
    if(document.getElementById("no_of_year").value=="1") { 
      document.getElementById("interest_rate").value="9.5" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("no_of_year").value=="2") { 
      document.getElementById("interest_rate").value="10" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("no_of_year").value=="3") { 
      document.getElementById("interest_rate").value="10.5" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("no_of_year").value=="4") { 
      document.getElementById("interest_rate").value="11" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("no_of_year").value=="5") { 
      document.getElementById("interest_rate").value="11.5" 
    } 
  } 
</script> 

<h4><%= f.label :periods, class:'required' %></h4>
<select name="deposit[no_of_year]" id="no_of_year" onChange="deposit()"> 
  <option value="">select</option> 
  <option value="1">1</option> 
  <option value="2">2</option> 
  <option value="3">3</option> 
  <option value="4">4</option> 
  <option value="5">5</option> 
</select> 

<h4><%= f.label :interest_rate, class:'required' %>
<%= f.text_field :interest_rate, :id => "interest_rate", :value => "" %></h4>
```

My model:

```
before_save :calculate_age
def calculate_age
  self.age = ((DateTime.now - date_of_birth) / 365.25).to_i
end
```

Comment: Do you any `validation` set on `age` field in your model?

Comment: @Pavan: yeah but i removed the validation now and having the same problem again

Comment: Did you restarted the server after that?

Comment: Can you post your full model code(the validations part)?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the `date_of_birth` value to your model?

Comment: @Pavan:i didn't include any validation in model.

Comment: @RichPeck: yes i'm passing date_of_birth value

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.  May I suggest some jquery?  Let me know if this helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function deposit(){
    var age = $("#no_of_year").val();
    var interestRate = 9 + (0.5*age);
    $("#interest_rate").val(interestRate);
}
</script>
```

Comment: its working but it shows the same error.i don't know exactly where the error is?

Comment: if age is 58 and above,the above code is not working.i removed the validation.

Comment: I suspect that it might have something to do with negative values.  Can you show the result of DateTime.now - date_of_birth?

Comment: @user3743250: self.age = ((DateTime.now - date_of_birth) / 365.25).to_i it will give the age calculation. date_of_birth value is given manually.

Comment: So, I know the formula but it would be a good idea to confirm the results somehow.  Are you sure ((Datetime.now - date_of_birth)/365.25).to_i = the desired result?  Just check it out and we'll go one from there, ok?